# Javascript add method using object.prototype doesnt work

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

New to JS on the whole and I'm trying to add a method to a JS Object. 
I have an object;

```
function Population() {
  this.size = 30;
  this.items = [];
  this.generateRandom;
};
```

I wanted to define the generateRandom method later on as follows

```
Population.prototype.generateRandom = function() {
 ....code here...
}
```

But I'm getting the error

"generateRandom" is not a function

if I create a new population and try to run it I get this error;

```
//run the program
(function(){
    //let p = new Pool();
  let p = new Population();
  p.generateRandom();
  //p.generatePopulation();
    console.log(p);
}());
```

Comment: "I have an object". `Population()` is not an object, it's a function

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on? Declaring the function on the prototype should work.

Comment: Are you trying to define the function at a specific instance of `Population` only, or for all calls to `new Population()`

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy I edited it to show where, I got it when I called the generatePopulation function

Comment: @RiazShageer see my answer with code sample below. Could be you missed the `new` keyword?

Comment: _"I wanted to define the generateRandom method later on"_ What do you mean by "later on"?

Comment: @guest271314 im doing it for all instances. But was making it into a library. So wanted to leave that function up to lib users to define

Comment: If the decision is left up to library users to implement, why are you trying implement the feature for them? To determine how the process does or does not work? You can use `class` to define the object and library users can use `extends` to add a property to the original `class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work as is - try running this (took the liberty to put some code in the function):

```js
function Population() {
  this.size = 30;
  this.items = [];
};

Population.prototype.generateRandom = function() {
  for(let i = 0; i < this.size; i++)
    this.items.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
  return this.items;
};

let p = new Population();
console.log(p.generateRandom());
```

Comment: Thanks man. Im not sure why it doesnt
Here is the full fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rshageer/t8nfhun5/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's your `this.generateRandom;` at line 3 which is the cause of your problem. It's unnecessary.

Also, since you want to define an object, you may want to use the `class` keyword :

```
class Population {
  constructor() {
    this.size = 30;
    this.items = [];
  }
  generateRandom() {
    // ...your function here
  }
}
```